# Multiple errors generated by netbeans auto-code when inserting jButton event through GUI

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I've made a jFrame and jPanel with many buttons with the Netbeans assistant.
After hours of work, in a perfectly working code, each time I try to insert a new event, the code generated by the assistant produces hundreds of errors all around the class.

Anyone have experienced this issue?
Anyone got a fix?

Thanks.

The generated code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package prog08notes;

/**
 *
 * @author Diego
 */
public class VentanaMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    String action = "";
    String historic = "";

    /**
     * Creates new form VentanaMenu
     */
    public VentanaMenu() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this
     * method is always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPopupMenu1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        popupMenu1 = new java.awt.PopupMenu();
        jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jPopupMenu2 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        codAl = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        inXAR = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        inWEB = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        inMSO = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        inPROG = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        output = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        introAs = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        jMenu1.setText("jMenu1");

        jMenu2.setText("jMenu2");

        popupMenu1.setLabel("popupMenu1");

        jMenu3.setText("jMenu3");

        jMenu4.setText("jMenu4");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Menú de opciones");

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("1");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("0");

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("2");
        jButton3.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton3MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("3");
        jButton4.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton4MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setText("4");

        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton6.setText("5");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Introducir en la lista de alumnos");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Visualizar la nota media del módulo");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Visualizar medias de todos los alumnos");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Salir");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Visualizar nota determinada del alumno");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Informe global del curso");

        output.setEditable(false);
        output.setColumns(20);
        output.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(output);

        jLabel8.setText("COD AL");

        jLabel9.setText("SiPROG");

        jLabel10.setText("SiMSO");

        jLabel11.setText("SiWEB");

        jLabel12.setText("SiXAR");

        introAs.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "SiPROG", "SiMSO", "SiWEB", "SiXAR" }));
        introAs.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                introAsItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        introAs.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                introAsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        jComboBox2.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                jComboBox2ItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel13.setText("SALIDA");

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setBackground(getBackground());
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.setText("INSTRUCCIONES:\nIntroducir los datos (si se requieren) en las casillas \no menús correspondientes.\nPulsar el botón del menú deseado.\nLos datos se mostrarán en la ventana inferior.");
        jTextArea1.setBorder(null);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 256, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jButton4)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jButton1)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jButton3)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                                                .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel11)
                                                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel12))
                                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(codAl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                                .addComponent(inPROG, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                .addComponent(inMSO, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                                                .addComponent(inWEB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                                .addComponent(inXAR, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(introAs, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addGap(312, 312, 312)))))
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jButton5)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jButton6)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 294, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addContainerGap())))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11)
                    .addComponent(jLabel12))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(inXAR, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(inWEB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(inMSO, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(inPROG, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(codAl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(introAs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton5)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton6)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(jLabel13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 306, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void introAsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void jComboBox2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void introAsItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                         
String asignatura = (String) introAs.getSelectedItem();
if (asignatura.equals("SiPROG")) {cod = 1; };
if (asignatura.equals("SiMSO")) {cod = 2; };
if (asignatura.equals("SiWEB")) {cod = 3; };
if (asignatura.equals("SiXAR")) {cod = 4; };
    }                                        

    private void jButton4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
float media = pn.mitjanaModul(cod);
        writeConsole("La nota media del módulo " + introAs.getSelectedItem()+ " es " + media + ".");
    }                                     
   
    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
//Creación de alumno
boolean check = true; 
if (Alumno.validaCodi(codAl.getText())) {
try{
float f1 = Float.parseFloat(inPROG.getText());
if (!(0 <= f1 && 10 >= f1)) {check =false;};
float f2 = Float.parseFloat(inMSO.getText());
if (!(0 <= f2 && 10 >= f2)) {check =false;};
float f3 = Float.parseFloat(inWEB.getText());
if (!(0 <= f3 && 10 >= f3)) {check =false;};
float f4 = Float.parseFloat(inXAR.getText());
if (!(0 <= f4 && 10 >= f4)) {check =false;};
if (check) {
float grades []= {f1,f2,f3,f4};
pn.inserirAlumne(codAl.getText(), grades);
    writeConsole("Insertado el alumno " + codAl.getText());
    }                                     

    private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

else { writeConsole("Las notas deben estar entre 0 y 10.");};}
catch (Exception ex) {
        writeConsole("Debes rellenar correctamente los campos del alumno.");
    }}
else writeConsole("El código de alumno está formado por 3 mayúsculas y 2 dígitos.");
    }
    
    //Método de escritura en la consola
    public void writeConsole (String s){
        action = s;
        historic = historic + "\n" + action;
        output.setText(historic);     
    }
     
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VentanaMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VentanaMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VentanaMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VentanaMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new VentanaMenu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField codAl;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inMSO;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inPROG;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inWEB;
    private javax.swing.JTextField inXAR;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> introAs;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu jPopupMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu jPopupMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea output;
    private java.awt.PopupMenu popupMenu1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

//Variables propias
    Prog08Notes pn = new Prog08Notes();
    byte cod = 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please don't post images of code, instead post the code as code-formatted text, please [edit] your question to include it. Somehow you managed to delete your variable declarations. But instead of using Netbeans GUI builder, write the code by-hand, this way you'll be learning the language and framework (Swing) rather than an IDE that when run in our own IDEs (e.g. Eclipse / IntelliJ) might or might not work.

Comment: Not related to your problem but, don't use a MouseListener on your buttons. Instead you should be using an ActionListener.

Comment: *"Anyone got a fix?"* Use the IDE to write Java code, rather than let it use you via the automagic functionality.